# AES crypto used int SaltStack

Tags: cryptography, aes, salt-stack

Does anybody know where I can find infos on cryto used in saltstack. I know it's AES but doesnt find info on key size (128/256/... ) and if it's possible to configure?

The source code seems to make référence to AES 128 , 1024 key size , HMAC-SHA256  and AES-CBC but as I'm not fluent with python and it's not clear to me If and how I can do AES256.

Thanks

Comment: Default key size [seems to be](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/817cd9f42aaf493816a2e962a1798b1ec834476e/salt/crypt.py#L1190) 192 bit.

Comment: The talk about security at SaltStack just blows my mind. It seems they really haven't got a clue. Maybe I should do a review, but I'm afraid I'll find way too much - if I can get any documentation that is. Sheesh. Anyway, off topic here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about security protocols, not programming / development. Try crypto.SE or security.SE instead.

Comment: Reposted by the original author here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39967/aes-crypto-used-in-saltstack